# Mackinac hop and usage

Tags: hops

What is the best way to utilize the potential of Mackinac hops is a hop-forward beer? Knowing that it is an aroma hop, is it best in late boil addition or whirlpool ? Or do it's qualities come out best in dry-hopping?

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends ... do you want the flavours and aromas that would come from late boil additions, whirlpool or Dry Hop. Each will contribute different flavour profiles to the finished beer and each will be prefered by different people.

Also, it is sold as an aroma hop but has an average of 11.5% AA so would also work well in bittering, and I would sugest would lend itself to making a single hop brew.

My standard approach using a new hop would be to try with just a late hop and see what I think and then dry hop some of that to see how it differs.

If you want fully hop forward then I would advise doing all 3 to get a blend of the available flavour profiles from the hop.

Experiment, see what works best for the recipe, your or your freind's tastes; and if you do some trial brews please report back what you find.